# High Level Consumer Failure in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have the following Kafka Setup

```
    Number of producer : 1
    Number of topics : 1
    Number of partitions : 2
    Number of consumers : 3 (with same group id)
    Number of Kafka cluster : none(single Kafka server)
    Zookeeper.session.timeout : 1000
    Consumer Type : High Level Consumer
```

Producer produces messages without any specific partitioning logic(default partitioning logic).
Consumer 1 consumes message continuously. I am abruptly killing consumer 1 and I would except consumer 2 or consumer 3 to consume the messages after the failure of consumer 1.

In some cases rebalance occurs and consumer 2 starts consuming messages. This is perfectly fine.
But in some cases either consumer 2 or consumer 3 is not at all consuming. I have to manually kill all the consumers and start all three consumers again.
Only after this restart consumer 1 starts consuming again.

Precisely rebalance is successful in some cases while in some cases rebalance is not successful. 
Is there any configuration that I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka uses Zookeeper to coordinate high level consumers.

From http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html :

> Partition Owner registry
>
> Each broker partition is consumed by a single consumer within a given
>   consumer group. The consumer must establish its ownership of a given
>   partition before any consumption can begin. To establish its
>   ownership, a consumer writes its own id in an ephemeral node under the
>   particular broker partition it is claiming.
>
> /consumers/[group_id]/owners/[topic]/[broker_id-partition_id] -->
>   consumer_node_id (ephemeral node)

There is a known ephemeral nodes quirk that they can linger up to 30 seconds after ZK client suddenly goes down :
http://developers.blog.box.com/2012/04/10/a-gotcha-when-using-zookeeper-ephemeral-nodes/

So you may be running into this if you expect consumer 2 and 3 to start reading messages immediately after #1 is terminated.

You can also check that /consumers/[group_id]/owners/[topic]/[broker_id-partition_id] contains correct data after rebalancing.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I have couple of doubts.    1)How can I make sure that the ephemeral node is deleted when a new client is started. Is there a way to specify this in my consumer program.      2)Where can i find the /consumers directory. I can see only kafkalogs dir under /tmp (Red hat linux).

Comment: 1) Ephemeral nodes are deleted by Zookeeper servers automatically on client disconnection. I believe disconnection is detected by lack of heartbeat message responses for 30 seconds. It should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: 2) /consumers/... is not located on a real filesystem. Zookeeper holds the data in an internal tree like structure that resembles a filesystem. There is a tool that allows to view and modify it. It is usually located in /opt/zookeeper/current/bin/zkCli.sh on the box, where ZK in installed. zkCli.sh supports commands like ls, get, put rmr etc. See http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.4/zookeeperStarted.html for details